# iframe in IE triggers javascript download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I am trying to make an ajax call for analytics tracking to pardot but i cant run the ajax call so instead i resorted to doing a hidden iframe. But now in IE it tries to download the js file returned in the frame. How can i avoid this issue.

HTML

```
<iframe id="trackingFrame" name="trackingFrame" src="" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            /*var filetypes = /\.(zip|exe|pdf|doc*|xls*|ppt*|mp3)$/i;*/
           if(msieversion() == false){
            var filetypes = /\.(pdf)$/i;
            var baseHref = '';
            if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined)
                baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');
                jQuery('a').each(function() {
                    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                    if (href && href.match(filetypes)) {

                        jQuery(this).click(function() {
                            var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
                            var filePath = href;

                            $('#trackingFrame').attr('src', 
                                'https://pi.pardot.com/analytics?ver=3&visitor_id='+pi.tracker.visitor_id+'&pi_opt_in='+
                                '&campaign_id='+piCId+'&account_id='+piAId+'&title='+'&pi_points=10'+'&url='+filePath+'&referrer='
                            ).load(function(){
                                window.location.href = filePath;
                            });

                            return false;
                        });
                    }
                });
           }
        });
```

Comment: BTW it works in chrome and firefox

Comment: I ended up switching from pardot to Mautic, more control